# Can sst_state_transfer be set to rsync with innodb as storage engine in Galera cluster?

Tags: mysql, innodb, mariadb, galera, mariadb-10.2

Galera cluster *wsrep-sst-method* [docs](http://galeracluster.com/documentation-webpages/mysqlwsrepoptions.html#wsrep-sst-method) states:

> You can only use rsync when anode is starting. You cannot use it with
>   a running InnoDB storage engine.

I do have InnoDB storage engine configured in MariaDB Galera cluster and the *wsrep-sst-method* is set to *rsync* and state transfers do happen on starting nodes.

What's wrong with this configuration? Is *xtrabackup* the only *wsrep-sst-method* to be used with *innodb* storage engine?

Answer (score 1):

> Is xtrabackup the only wsrep-sst-method to be used with innodb storage engine?

All Galera clusters are InnoDB, MyISAM (and derivates) not supported (expect `mysql` database with wrappers for managing users/permissions).

No, nothing wrong with your configuration. You can use Logical State Snapshot `mysqldump` or the Physical State Snapshot `rsync` and `xtrabackup`. See [State Snapshot Transfers](http://galeracluster.com/documentation-webpages/sst.html) for a comparison.

A physical restore always needs a restart. The same concept like backup/restore.

In normal operations only `IST` is needed. `SST` is only needed when something goes wrong (maybe infrastructure issue) and the node is out-of-sync. Mostly the DBA cares about such cases.

- State Snapshot Transfers (SST) Where a snapshot of the entire node
  state transfers.
- Incremental State Transfers (IST) Where only the missing transactions transfer.

Comment: MariaDB (10.1.26+, 10.2.10) also has the [wsrep_sst_methods](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/galera-cluster-system-variables/#wsrep_sst_method) option 'mariabackup', which uses the MariaDB Backup package, which is a fork of Percona XtraBackup.